# Storing a python script output to a variable in linux and run a wget command

Tags: python, linux, shell

So I made a python script that retrieves a url link and returns it as an output. Just to keep it simple, the content of the python script would be just:

```
print("https://www.testweb.com/file=ejfeafjaiaefjaof")
```

For example, if i execute the python script in my terminal:

```
python retrieve_url.py
```

it outputs:

```
https://www.testweb.com/file=ejfeafjaiaefjaof
```

So I then would like to utilize the "wget" command in linux with the url that is returned by my python script, so that i could do something like:

```
wget https://www.testweb.com/file=ejfeafjaiaefjaof
```

But instead, is it possible to store the python output url in a variable and execute a linux script in one go? I was thinking something like creating an executable script, **run.sh**

```
python retrieve_url.py
wget **some argument to store the python output**
```

and just use ./run.sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` just needs to read the URL from stdin, using `-i-` flag:

```
python retrieve_url.py | wget -i-
```

Output:

```
--2021-01-14 16:15:17--  https://example.org/
Resolving example.org (example.org)... 93.184.216.34
Connecting to example.org (example.org)|93.184.216.34|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1256 (1,2K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                                        100%[============================================================================================================>]   1,23K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2021-01-14 16:15:17 (20,0 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [1256/1256]

FINISHED --2021-01-14 16:15:17--
Total wall clock time: 0,6s
Downloaded: 1 files, 1,2K in 0s (20,0 MB/s)
```

Comment: Mayer, thanks! If the wget is retrieving a zipped file, and i would like to follow that up with an unzipping process, would it be "| unzip -o-" after the wget statement?

Comment: @Maxxx: `wget` needs to write the download to stdout. `python retrieve_url.py | wget -i- -qO- | tar xvf -`

Answer (score 1):

To save the output of your python script like this

```
test=$(python test.py)

echo $test
"https://www.testweb.com/file=ejfeafjaiaefjaof"
```